# stderr can only be printed on screen but cannot be piped

Tags: bash, stdout, stderr, postfix-mta

I just encountered something strange about stdout and stderr!

This works perfectly:

```
$ ( { { echo "This is stdout"; echo "This is stderr" 1>&2; } | sed "s/^/stdout captured - /"; } 3>&2 2>&1 1>&3 ) | sed "s/^/stderr captured - /"
stderr captured - This is stderr
stdout captured - This is stdout
```

However, see this:

```
$ sudo postfix status >/dev/null
postfix/postfix-script: the Postfix mail system is not running
$ sudo postfix status 2>/dev/null
$
```

I think, definitely the message on screen is STDERR, BUT:

```
$ ( { { sudo postfix status; } | sed "s/^/stdout captured - /"; } 3>&2 2>&1 1>&3 ) | sed "s/^/stderr captured - /"
$
```

Nothing captured. I simply issue below command and get nothing again:

```
$ `sudo postfix status 2>/tmp/somelog` && cat /tmp/somelog
$
```

It seems beyond my knowledge about `bash`

ps: I'm on `MAC OSX 10.11.6`, terminal.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo: "$ \`sudo postfix status 2>/tmp/somelog\` && cat /tmp/somelog" need to be "$ sudo postfix status 2>/tmp/somelog && cat /tmp/somelog"

Comment: What happens if you replace `2>&1` with `2>/dev/tty`, or if you simply omit the pipe to sed? My guess is that this has nothing to do with the shell, but that postfix is checking if stderr is a tty and behaving differently when it is not.

Comment: @WilliamPursell, I think you've shed light on me. Your explanation is reasonable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this has to do with the `postfix` command actually behaving differently when it is part of a pipe.

I tried this on my system :

```
sudo postfix status 2>log
```

And `log` turns out empty.  Same thing with :

```
postfix status 2>log
```

It seems `postfix` suppresses this output when its output is not going to a terminal.